# Low-rank approximation of the STFT matrix : good audio compression technique?

Tags: fft, audio, stft, compression

I recently heard about this interesting math tool:

1. With a matrix $A$, compute the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) ($ A = U \Sigma ^tV$ factorization, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix containing the "singular values")
2. Keep the $k$ biggest singular values only and discard the lowest ones (set them to $0$); this gives $\tilde{\Sigma}$.
3. Then $ \tilde{A} = U \tilde{\Sigma} ^tV$ will be the **best rank-$k$** approximation of A.

Step #2 allows to save a lot of storage size, and thus this can be thought as a compression technique. See [this example](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxuYXNsdW5kZXJpY3xneDpkMTI4OTI1NTc4YjRlOGE) on image processing.

---

Then I wanted to try this on STFT. I did :

```
Audio sound ---> STFT ---> low-rank-approximation of the STFT matrix thanks to SVD ---> iSTFT
```

The good thing is that it helps to save storage size, compression! 
The bad thing is that it only resulted in **loosing the high frequencies** :

Original STFT (listen to the [audio file](http://gget.it/9echa12m/imagine.wav)):

[image]

After low-rank-approximation STFT (high frequencies more or less lost) (listen to the [audio file](http://gget.it/n7a0ggre/imagine(stft_svd).wav)):

[image]

**Is there a way to turn this "low-rank approximation of STFT" into something better?** And if not, why?

Comment: The problem with low rank SVD approximations generally is that you have no control over what components ("singular" vectors; SVD equivalent of eigenvectors) the decomposition will find.  Would just using $k$ largest FFT coefficients do any better?